# Completely rounded single border

Tags: html, css, navigation

I currently have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr175x8r/) and I am wondering if I can make the bottom border completely rounded.

This is the specific piece of CSS that won't work:

```
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
```

I want the bottom borders to be  completely rounded rectangles like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZZoy.png)

Is there any way to do this using CSS and HTML??

Comment: Of course this does not work like you want it to, because your elements only have a bottom border. I’d suggest inserting a pseudo element with a top and bottom border …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go :)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/Lr175x8r/5/)

```
nav a:after {
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:20px; right:0; left:0; bottom:0;
    border-radius: 45px;
}
```

### **Updated code**

Instead of adding an ID to each item, you can convert this to an ul menu like the following, and then you can target it via nth-child property in CSS.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/Lr175x8r/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav li:nth-child(1) a:after {
    background: blue;
}

.nav li:nth-child(2) a:after {
    background: yellow;
}

.nav li:nth-child(3) a:after {
    background: red;
}

.nav li:nth-child(4) a:after {
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly :) I just added 

#nav-home:after{background:#B8312F}
#nav-services:after{background:#1fa67a}
#nav-work:after{background:#2980b9}
#nav-contact:after{background:#2c3e50}

To get my desired colours :)

Comment: @james55555 regarding the colors please check the updated code for a better approach to do it :) hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ?

```css
#first{width:300px;background-color:green;}
#second{width:80px;background-color:red;height:10px;border-radius:5px;position:relative;top:-15px;left:3px;}
#third{width:80px;background-color:red;height:10px;border-radius:5px;position:relative;top:-25px;left:99px;}
#forth{width:80px;background-color:red;height:10px;border-radius:5px;position:relative;top:-35px;left:200px;}
```

```html
<div id="first">&nbsp; </div><div id="second">&nbsp; </div><div id="third">&nbsp;</div><div id="forth">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: This is how he want the border to appear but not the wanted result, please read the question carefully.